# Should I put the time range first in the WHERE statement in CnosQL to optimize queries?

Tags: database

Any difference in terms of the query performance regarding the following two CnosQL queries? I mean, do I have to put time range  first in the WHERE statement in order to fast boot the query execution?

```
select * from air where time >= '2021-09-10T04:00:00Z' AND time < '2021-09-30T04:00:00Z' AND "station" = 'LianYunGang'
```

```
select * from air where "station" = 'LianYunGang' AND time >= '2021-09-10T04:00:00Z' AND time < '2021-09-30T04:00:00Z'
```

I didn't find any doc yet [here](https://cnosdb.github.io/docs/content/cnosdb/latest/cnosql/cnosql_syntax.html).

Comment: I don't know the exact behaviour of your database, but in general, for most flavors of SQL, the optimiser would be free to evaluate the `WHERE` clause in any order.  You cannot "force" a certain query plan by using a certain order in the `WHERE` clause.  Rather, you would add an index in order to speed things up.

Comment: I was hoping to optimize in some certain way. I assume it doesn't matters but I couldn't see any docs about this or I have to read the source code. Thx for the explanation.